# Advice on replacing FacebookAgent (REST) authentication with Facebook Connect SDK on iOS

Tags: facebook, sdk, ios4

I inherited an iOS app that is currently using an authentication library called [FacebookAgent](http://amanpages.com/iphone-app-development-core-sdk-cocoa/facebookagent-update-now-upload-a-photo-and-then-change-status-in-a-single-call-using-facebook-connect-for-iphone/). If unaware, this uses the soon-to-be-or-is-now-deprecated Facebook REST authentication system.

I'll be replacing this with the Facebook Connect SDK. Does anyone know if it's possible to easily switch from the FacebookAgent REST authentication system to the Facebook Connect SDK without having to back out all of the FacebookAgent methods?

Thanks in advance for any advice.